# a program that shows the following sequence

Tags: python

i wanna write a program that returns the following sequence to the number that the user enters.
the sequence is :
4, 6, 12, 12, 24, 18, 36, 24, 48, 30, 60, 36, ...
and the formula for that is :
f(x) = {f(x - 1) * 2 for odd numbers}and{ x * 3 for even numbers}
$  you can see the mathematic formula in the picture[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiKfQ.jpg)

for example:

if user enter 5 as an input should be seen

[4, 6, 12, 12, 24]

as an output.

please help i wanna solve this ...

```
inp = input("Enter the input separated with spaces ").split()
output=[]
for i in inp:
    if int(i)%2==0:
        output.append(int(i)*3)
    else:
        output.append((int(i)-1)*6)
print(output)
```

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? What code have you written? Does it produce the wrong output? Are there any error messages? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you having trouble?

Comment: i have a problem with the formula

Comment: the formula for this question has two parts and i dont know how to write this part

Comment: Piecewise functions like `f(x) = {a for x in [some set]}or{b for x in [another set]}` are basically `if` statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved with a simple code give below

```
inp = input("Enter the input separated with spaces ").split()
output=[]
for i in inp:
    if int(i)%2==0:
        output.append(int(i)*3)
    else:
        output.append((int(i)-1)*6)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy implementation that might get you closer to what you want:

```
def funny_function(x):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        return x * 3
    return funny_function(x-1) * 2


def main():
    for x in range(1, 30):
        print(f"f({x}) = {funny_function(x)}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

the output looks like:

```
f(1) = 0
f(2) = 6
f(3) = 12
f(4) = 12
f(5) = 24
f(6) = 18
f(7) = 36
f(8) = 24
f(9) = 48
f(10) = 30
f(11) = 60
f(12) = 36
f(13) = 72
f(14) = 42
f(15) = 84
f(16) = 48
f(17) = 96
f(18) = 54
f(19) = 108
f(20) = 60
f(21) = 120
f(22) = 66
f(23) = 132
f(24) = 72
f(25) = 144
f(26) = 78
f(27) = 156
f(28) = 84
f(29) = 168
```

I hope you can take it further from here.